# Вывод нескольких строк в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, текст

```py
i = 100
uah = 1
kop = 5
while i<1500:
    i=i+100
    with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
        print(i, "grams:", uah, "UAH", kop, "kop", file=f)
```

Выводит: "1500 grams: 1 UAH 5 kop"
Должно выводить:
"100 grams: 1 UAH 5 kop"
"200 grams: 1 UAH 5 kop"
...
"1500 grams: 1 UAH 5 kop"

Comment: Знать бы что во входном файле, а именно - что читаем. Похоже тут операция не над той переменной что нужна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При открытии файла в режиме `'w'` старое содержимое файла каждый раз стирается. Нужно внести цикл внутрь блока `with open`:

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    while i<1500:
        i=i+100
        print(i, "grams:", uah, "UAH", kop, "kop", file=f)
```

Для циклов с одинаковым шагом удобнее использовать цикл for:

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in range(100, 1501, 100):  # 1501 - чтобы 1500 тоже попадало в диапазон счетчика цикла
        print(i, "grams:", uah, "UAH", kop, "kop", file=f)
```